# descargar un fichero directamente con javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hola estoy intentando que cuando visito una de mis paginas con fotos baje la foto directamente. Pero cuando lo hago no funciona. Intente muchas cosas pero no funciono.

Alguien me podría explicar como puedo hacer para que baje mi foto directamente?

El código de mi html sería el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function insert(){
            var src = document.getElementById("gamediv");
            var img = document.createElement("img");
            img.src = "imagen.png";
            src.appendChild(img);
        }
     </script>
 </head>
<style>
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.bgimg {
    background-image: url('fondo.jpg');
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
    font-size: 25px;
}

#gamediv{
    height: 20%;
}

.topleft {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 16px;
}

.bottomleft {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 16px;
}

.middle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
}

hr {
    margin: auto;
    width: 40%;
}
</style>
<body>

<div class="bgimg">
  <div class="topleft">
    <!--<p>Logo</p>-->
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
    <!--<h1>COMING SOON</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>35 days left</p>-->
  </div>
  <div class="bottomleft">
    <!--<p>Some text</p>-->
  </div>
  <div id="gamediv">
         <script type="text/javascript">
             insert();
         </script>
     </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Intente con php pero me abría otra ventana. Intente con javascript pero no sé como puedo hacer para que baje mi foto directamente.

Comment: Desde PHP puedes forzar una descarga con header https://www.ngeeks.com/forzar-descargas-de-archivos-con-php/ y desde .htaccess también puedes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14388994/forcing-a-download-using-filesmatch-in-htaccess-at-www-root

Answer (score 0):

Bueno tienes una solución bastante simple, solo tienes que asignar a cada elemento una clase. Ejemplo:

```
<a class="aDescargar" href="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg" ><img src="http://qnimate.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/images2.jpg">

<a class="aDescargar" href="http://wac.2f9ad.chicdn.net/802F9AD/u/joyent.wme/public/wme/assets/ec050984-7b81-11e6-96e0-8905cd656caf.jpg?v=30"><img src="http://wac.2f9ad.chicdn.net/802F9AD/u/joyent.wme/public/wme/assets/ec050984-7b81-11e6-96e0-8905cd656caf.jpg?v=30"></a>
```

Como puedes ver los dos elementos **a** contienen una imagen.

El codigo javascript es muy simple.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //Coger todos los elementos que quieres descargar.
    var aElements = document.getElementsByClassName('aDescargar'); 
    //A cada uno de ellos le asignas el atributo download a true.

    for(a of aElements){
        a.download=true;
        //Como tiene el atributo downlaod=true, simplemente haciendo click la imagen se descarga
        a.click();
    }

</script>
```

Listo ahora ya se descarga automaticamente.

Espero haberte ayudado!!!

Comment: Me lo descarga automaticamente, sin hacer clic.

Comment: En el bucle se llama al método click para descargarlo automáticamente, lo que puedes hacer es quitarlo. Pero si lo quitas las fotos solo se van a descargar cuando tu(usuario) le haga click.